# How do I show content only if logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication

Our website uses online software from a company called the [DecoNetwork](http://www.deconetwork.com). It allows our customers to log in and keep track of their orders yadda yadda. I was able to use their code for a login form and use it on our custom website.

```
    <form action="http://cheapcustomtees.deco-apparel.com/user/login?mobi=0" method="post">             
    <input type="hidden" name="_pc_session_id" value="7eb5d16ed18b074967ee0cf333d24417"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_pc_skey" value="wynkunatrixikuquunetycyxomynkozatrivozichardaru"/>
        Login: &nbsp;<input type="textbox" name="user[login]"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="user[password]"/>
        Remember me: &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="1" checked="true" class="auto" />       
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="bigbutton" style="font-size:10pt; font-family:Museo700; cursor:pointer;" />
    </form>
```

If possible, I would like to display content based on if the user is logged in or out. If logged out, show the login form. Otherwise, show something else.

Is something like this possible with someone else's sessions? If so, can you give me an example as I am still new with PHP?

Comment: That might help if I were creating the sessions myself, which I know how to do. My question, when dumbed down, is whether or not it's possible to do what I am looking to do with someone else's sessions. "Read about sessions" isn't exactly helpful. I suppose if I asked about a certain variable you would answer "Read about variables"?

Comment: unless the session is set on your domain, you have NO access to it. and @bwoebi is right, you can read that in the manual page on sessions

Comment: You would have to connect to the online software and check whether the user's session is still active. This is called Single Sign On. Whether possible or not depends entirely on the software though, plus there are possible cross domain issues getting hold of the session value as Dagon points out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is never possible to use sessions, or cookies of 3rd party websites unless it has been setup to do so.

There are several vulnerabilities that would theoretically allow you to such as..

- Cross-site scripting ("XSS")

Disregarding the fact it is completely illegal, you would still have to do quite a few fancy kungfu moves with cURL to check whether the cookie you stole through XSS is a vaild, and active one. You would also have to be lucky that the user is using a browser that does not block reflective XSSs; assuming you do not have a persistent one.

Also, even if you manage to obtain a cookie, you will still have to be lucky with the session management of the 3rd party is not IP address based.

Besides vulnerabilities, or websites that have been setup to do a strange type of authorization, this is not possible, and should not be possible ( it would pose a serious security threat ).

If you do not want to store any sensitive information of your users, such as passwords, the closest thing that comes to mind is OpenID.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I didn't realize it was so in-depth. I will probably just end up using the website they supply with their software and do some major heavy duty HTML and CSS alterations to make it look somewhat decent.